# Mysql query SUM group?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have this table example

**ORDER**

- orders_id
- order_article_id
- order_invoice_id
- order_customer_id
- order_qty

And rows example

- 66   8   32  29  15
- 66   8   32  29  30

I do query something like this

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_invoice_id = 1
```

On loop i got all results simple, order_article_id, order_qty, but i got two results,
 because order_inovice_id is the same.

**RESULT 1**

order_article_id 8
order_qty **15**

**RESULT 2**

order_article_id 8
order_qty **30**

What i need to get just one result, that i can group and count result by the order_article_id

This is result what i need

**RESULT**

order_article_id 8
order_qty **45**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, alter the where condition to suit the data.

```
SELECT order_article_id , SUM(order_qty) as order_qty
FROM orders WHERE order_invoice_id = 32
GROUP BY order_article_id
```

**Result**

```
| ORDER_ARTICLE_ID | ORDER_QTY |
|------------------|-----------|
|                8 |        45 |
```

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    (`orders_id` int, `order_article_id` int, `order_invoice_id` int, `order_customer_id` int, `order_qty` int)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (`orders_id`, `order_article_id`, `order_invoice_id`, `order_customer_id`, `order_qty`)
VALUES
    (66, 8, 32, 29, 15),
    (66, 8, 32, 29, 30)
;
```

<kbd>[See SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cda9/4)</kbd>

Comment: please define "not work" what is the result or error? The SQL syntax is exceptionally simple

Comment: @Gorostas my answer is edited, you need to ensure the where returns data

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a GROUP BY query with SUM aggregated function:

```
SELECT
  order_article_id,
  SUM(qty) as sum_qty
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  order_invoice_id=1
GROUP BY
  order_article_id
```

Comment: Thsi does not owrk also

Comment: @Gorostas what error do you get? do you get wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(order_qty) as 'Total Quantity'
FROM orders
WHERE order_article_id = 8 
// where order_article_id in (1,2,3) if you have more id's and just want those
GROUP by order_article_id
```